# Unable to get project info and source control from a particular machine

Tags: tfs, client

From one particular machine, we are unable to get the tfs 2010 project tree via the visual studio 2010 team explorer.

The connection with the tfs server is made, but only the top level project names are shown with a *red cross*. The tree under it remains empty. Web access is possible from this machine.

From all other machines everything works normally, so it must be a local machine issue.

What might be misconfigured on this client?

Otherwise there seem to be no problems on this XP machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalled IE, most probable cause is a mistake while editing the registry.

I discovered the cause when an Outlook mail could not be printed due to a dll problem.